# Means Adjusted Continuous Variable

Tags: regression, mean

I am trying to replicate a study that uses "means adjusted unemployment rates" as an explanatory variable in a regression analysis. What exactly does this mean? I want my explanatory variable to remain continuous whereas everything I am finding describes an "adjusted mean" as in a singular calculation and usually in reference to descriptive statistics.

Any information is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Cross Validated! Could you provide a quote or example reference where this term is used?

Comment: All it says is "UR is means adjusted rate of unemployment in year t and state s."

I'm wondering how you means adjusted the continuous variable UR?

Comment: Where does it say this? Can you give us the reference?

Answer (score 0):

"Means adjusted unemployment rate" is going to be a number just like "unemployment rate". It is adjusted by something, probably related to income (if the source does not provide details, that's a bad sign). There will be a MAUR for each time t and state s, just as there is a UR for each time and state.